# performance difference between <c:import url="child.jsp" /> and <jsp:include ...>

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I know the performance difference between the following two

1. Include directive (`<%@ include file="test.jsp" %>`): This includes the contents of the file during the compilation phase—i.e., when the page is converted to a servlet.
2. Include action (`<jsp:include page="test.jsp" flush="true" />`): This includes the contents of the file in the run-time—i.e., when a request is made for the page by the user.

But what about JSTL tag `<c:import url="child.jsp" />`
is the content included during the compilation phase or run-time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is included at runtime. And you can put an absolute URL there (you can include html from 3rd party sites)

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the <jsp:include /> tag it include a jsp a runtime. In this way you can use it recursively.

About the c:include...is a tag so (I think) it's a runtime phase...

Answer (score 0):

By default with c:import, the content of an imported resource is included inline into the JSP page at runtime. Although, it is also possible to access the resource a String object or a Reader object.

The URL could be absolute (any outside web app) or relative (to the context)

HTH